# Return to same iteration in try except

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except

I am trying to validate that a the user wants to exit if using any control characters.

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in range(items):
        func.load_item()
        try:
            func.dosomething(data)

        except (IOError, EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            save = input("Do you want to save? <y/n>")
            if save.lower() == "y":
                func.save_item()
            leave = input("do you want to exit? <y/n>")

            if leave.lower() == "y":
                print(leaving)
            else:
                # How can i return to the first item 
                continue
        func.save_item()
```

How can I return to the first item if there is a "n" prompted in the except block? I added a comment where I thought that the code should 
belong, but im having difficulties getting this functionality to work. Thank you.

Comment: Then use a `while` loop and control it with a counter.

Comment: unfortunately Python does not allow that kind of granular control with its `for` loops. @coldspeed is correct.

Comment: `for` in Python is what the `foreach` is in other languages.